# Why can't I remove Orderless from Plus?

Tags: sorting, attributes, arithmetic

I am making some random algebra equations, and I want to have the ordering be random too, such that if my random equation generator makes `x+1`, the output stays `x+1`, without reverting to `1+x`.

I have tried `ClearAttributes[Plus, Orderless]`, but it simply did not work - entering `x+1` returns `1+x`.

The following sort-of works:

```
Unprotect[Plus];
Format[Plus[a_, b_]] := ToString@a <> " + " <> ToString@b
```

But it uses `Unprotect`, converts everything to strings, and also doesn't work when `b` is a fraction (fractions `p/q` are represented as `p\n--\nq`).

Is there a nicer way to do this?

Also, I plan to convert everything to `TraditionalForm` at the end, so using that to control ordering won't work either.

Comment: I found another solution, which is again not that great (as in it is super slow), but at least it gives me the results I want: `Rasterize[TraditionalForm[a]]+Rasterize[TraditionalForm[b]]`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I see the problem but I don't understand the objective well enough to offer alternatives. Your suggested fix still makes x+1 turn into 1+x, right?

Comment: @Rojo actually, don't worry about it.  I figured it out.  `plus = Row[{#1, " + ", #2}] &;` was what I was looking for: `x~plus~1 // TraditionalForm` gives exactly what I want.

Comment: Yeah, that would work for 2 arguments, for more you can use Riffle. Row@Riffle[{##}, " + "] &. I would prefer using that as Format to plus more than as an ownvalue. Something like Format[plus[args__]] := 
 Interpretation[HoldForm[Plus[args]], plus[args]]

Comment: Also, perhaps you would like wrapping your code in Module (or Block, depending on what you are doing) with Plus=plus, so you can use the + symbol at will. Module[{Plus = plus}, x + 1]

Comment: @Rojo I find it interesting though, that after `ClearAttributes[Plus, Orderless]`, MMA still returns `1+x` even for `Plus[x,1]` input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the suggested edits from Rojo in the comments above, the following is what answers my question:

```
plus[args__] := Row[Riffle[{args}, " + "]]
```

Then, `Block[{Plus = plus}, x + 1 + i + 4 + z] // TraditionalForm` returns:

> [image]

Comment: Looks good, +1. The idea of using `Interpretation` however was so that the output, if used literally as input, would be interpreted as ´plus[x,1,y...]` if you wanted to further operate on that, even though it "looks like" plus. If you care about that then the second argument shouldn't be ´Row[Riffle...` but `plus[args]`. If you don't care about that then you can do without ´Interpretation´ and use your Row@Riffle or that HoldForm@Plus

Comment: @Rojo Yes - the whole point was just presentation anyway.  But do you have any ideas as to why `ClearAttributes` didn't work?

Comment: sorry for the late response. I was planning on digging into it before answering, but got sidetracked and lazy. So far I hadn't thought of a good reason why, and my lack of humility makes my ignorance default to "bug"

Comment: Hmmm... what about if he has terms with negative coefficients?

Comment: @JohnD - It's interesting you pointed that out. That issue was actually resolved in [another question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20714/how-do-i-get-a-two-term-polynomial-with-a-leading-negative-sign-to-display-in-th). A combination of that answer and maybe some tinkering should do the job.