# How do I get a two-term polynomial with a leading negative sign to display in the correct (i.e. textbook) order?

Tags: output-formatting, polynomials, order

The first three expressions evaluate as expected and the polynomial is displayed in what I would call "textbook" form. The last expression, however, switches the order of terms. Mathematica employs this change for two-term polynomials if it results in getting rid of the leading negative sign (at least that is the best I can deduce).

```
x^2 + x + 5 // TraditionalForm
(* x^2 + x + 5 *)

-x^2 + x + 5 // TraditionalForm
(* -x^2 + x + 5 *)

x^2 + x // TraditionalForm
(* x^2 + x *)

-x^2 + x // TraditionalForm
(* x - x^2 *)
```

These polynomials are the result of prior symbolic manipulation, so I cannot simply use `HoldForm` or the equivalent to maintain the desired order.

Is there a way to change this behavior in general so that the last expression displays as `-x^2 + x`? I can think of substitution rules to fix this particular example, but would like to find a robust solution that applies as transparently as possible across the board.

**Edit**

Additionally, `PolynomialForm` produces the same results:

```
PolynomialForm[-x^2 + x , TraditionalOrder -> True]
(* x - x^2 *)

PolynomialForm[-x^2 - x , TraditionalOrder -> True]
(* -x^2 - x *)
```

It seems that Mathematica will produce the traditional order for polynomial terms except when there are only two terms and reversing the order eliminates the leading negative sign.

Comment: I was expecting to close this question with a reference to `PolynomialForm[#, TraditionalOrder -> True] &` but I see that you're going the other way.  Let me think about that.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Yes, I already tried `PolynomialForm` and that produces the same results. I will add that information to the question because that will probably be a common thought pattern.

Comment: Previous questions relating to this usually creates a new function to handle `Plus`. But would be nice with a way that lets you override the displayed order of `Orderless` arguments.

Comment: Previous questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109306/preventing-plus-from-rearranging-things http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947071/controlling-order-of-variables-in-an-expression/3948995#3948995

Comment: @ssch I don't think those solve this one (which I assume is why you didn't post an answer.)  RandomBits doesn't want to *prevent* ordering, he wants to control it.

Comment: Another related question:[How to keep Collect[] result in order?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15744/245)

Answer (score 7):

Since the two other answers don't seem to do exactly what's needed, I'll try my luck:

```
order[poly_] := 
 Replace[Reverse@Sort[List @@ poly], List[x__] :> HoldForm[Plus[x]]]

order /@ {x^2 + x + 5, -x^2 + x + 5, x^2 + x, -x^2 - x}
```

> $\left\{x^2+x+5,-x^2+x+5,x^2+x,-x^2-
>    x\right\}$

Here I end up with `HoldForm` wrapping an expression that should have the sorted terms, and this ordering would be maintained when feeding it into `TraditionalForm` or `TeXForm`.

I avoided using `Row` for the output (and hence also don't use `Format` or `MakeBoxes`) so that I don't have to worry about getting things like $+\,-\,x$.

Comment: Well I was just getting around to this method myself but you were six minutes faster so +1. :-)

Comment: Jens, do you see anything wrong with my second method?  What do you see as the advantage or disadvantage of `Sort[List @@ #]` versus `MonomialList@#`?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard `MonomialList` is the right choice, I think. But using `Sort` seems like a cute, original twist.

Answer (score 5):

I hope there is a better way but here is something to build upon:

```
TraditionalForm @ Row[MonomialList@#, "+"] & /@
  {x^2 + x + 5, -x^2 + x + 5, x^2 + x, -x^2 + x}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Jens pointed out a bug in my original method.  Here's another:

```
HoldForm[+##] & @@ MonomialList@# & /@
 {x^2 + x + 5, -x^2 + x + 5, x^2 + x, -x^2 + x, -x^2 - x}
```

[image]

Comment: Similar `Row[MonomialList[-x^2 + x, {x}, "DegreeLexicographic"], "+"]`

Comment: Is it the case that `Plus@@MonomialList[expr] == expr` for any expression? If so, then I can define a format: `Format[xPlus[x___]] := Row[Riffle[{expr}, "+"]]` and then `xPlus := Plus` and then use `HoldForm[xPlus@@MonomialList[expr]]` to the display ordering that I want while still having a valid expression when the hold is released (because the xPlus will be changed to Plus).

Comment: After I upvoted this, I realized it's not quite right: Try `TraditionalForm@Row[MonomialList@#, "+"] &[-x^2 - x]` and you get $-x^2+\,-\,x$. The same error happens with the solution by @ssch.

Comment: @Jens Okay, maybe a hybrid of the two answers will work.  Let me try some stuff.

Answer (score 1):

```
poly[x_] := 
 Block[{Plus}, 
  x // Sort // Reverse // Evaluate // HoldForm // TraditionalForm]
poly[x - x^2]
(* -x^2+x *)
poly[-x^2 + x]
(* -x^2+x *)
```

Comment: This is the best answer, I think (+1). But do you really need `HoldFirst`?

Comment: @Jens This changes the order of all the other terms, which in my understanding is *not* desired.  I believe all but the last expression should agree with `{x^2 + x + 5, -x^2 + x + 5, x^2 + x, -x^2 + x} // TraditionalForm`.  That is to say, it should match my answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You're right. I thought `Sort` on blocked `Plus` is a clever idea, but it doesn't quite do what's needed either.

Comment: @Jens, Mr. Wizard good catches - guess I should have done more testing.

Comment: @Jens moreover, it fails with `-x + 1`.