# Why does Mathematica order polynomial forms in reverse from traditional order?

Tags: output-formatting, polynomials, language-design, traditional-form

I could very well be missing something obvious, but this has always bugged me with Mathematica and I don't know why it does it or how to fix it.

If I enter any polynomial, say, x^2 + x - 1 for example, the output is always in the form:

```
-1 + x + x^2
```

And again:

```
input: Expand[(x^2 - 1) ((-3 + x)^2 - 4)]
output: -5 + 6 x + 4 x^2 - 6 x^3 + x^4
```

I find this much more difficult to read than the traditional way, from highest power to lowest. Is there anything I can do to change this? I'm aware that TraditionalForm prints them properly, but it is generally not recommended to do calculations with TraditionalForm so I'd like to avoid that if possible. Then again, IS IT that bad to do calculations with TraditionalForm like it warns?

Comment: Orderless entities are placed in the same order that `Sort` uses. `Sort` works with very general expressions and has no notion of "polynomialhood". You might try using `TraditionalForm` on your expression, as that will often display polynomials, at least univariate ones, in the order you expect.

Comment: You can preform all calculations before applying `TraditionalForm`.

Comment: For two reasons, it's actually more natural to write a polynomial in terms of *ascending* powers of the variable x instead of the more usual, traditional notation with descending powers: (1) a polynomial is a special case of a power series, and power series are written with ascending powers of x; and (2) ascending powers lead more readily to the computationally efficient Horner's form a0 + x(a1 + x(a2 + x(...}) ...).

Comment: Related: [(6358)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6358/121),
[(15744)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15744/121),
[(20714)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20714/121),
[(30216)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30216/121)

Comment: The question asked *why* the terms are output in the order given by Mathematica. One justification is that it fits nicely with a Laurant expansion, which includes negative powers of the variable, too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As Daniel Lichtblau wrote in the comment you can use `TraditionalForm`

```
Expand[(x^2 - 1) ((-3 + x)^2 - 4)] // TraditionalForm
```

> $x^4-6 x^3+4 x^2+6 x-5$

However, it works perfectly only with univariate polynomials

```
Expand[(x + y + 1)^5] // TraditionalForm
```

> $x^5+5 x^4 y+5 x^4+10 x^3 y^2+20 x^3 y+10 x^3+10 x^2 y^3+30 x^2 y^2+30 x^2 y+10 x^2+5 x y^4+20 x y^3+30 x y^2+20 x y+5 x+y^5+5 y^4+10 y^3+10 y^2+5 y+1$

You can see that $5x$ is before $y^5$ and so on.

My solution consist in the manual sorting of monomials

```
OrderedForm = HoldForm[+##] & @@ MonomialList[#][[
     Ordering[Total[#] & @@@ CoefficientRules[#], All, GreaterEqual]]] &;

Expand[(x + y + 1)^5] // OrderedForm
```

> ```
> x^5+5 x^4 y+10 x^3 y^2+10 x^2 y^3+5 x y^4+y^5+5 x^4+20 x^3 y+30 x^2 y^2+20 x y^3+5 y^4+
> 10 x^3+30 x^2 y+30 x y^2+10 y^3+10 x^2+20 x y+10 y^2+5 x+5 y+1
> ```

Comment: I like your solution! I must say that I don't understand how your function works, I don't know much about anything that uses the # symbol in Mathematica yet, but it does order things well. The only downside is that it seems like calculations cannot be done until converted back to StandardForm. Is there a way around that?

Comment: @Brendan There is great compilation about such symbols: [What the @#%^&*?! do all those funny signs mean?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/4678). You don't need to perform calculations on converted expressions (`TraditionalForm`, `OrderedForm`, etc.). Just convert only the final result. If you want to see intermediate results use something like `(p3=p1+p2)//OrderedForm`.

Comment: Alternatively, one can use some *undocumented* functionality: `PolynomialForm[Expand[(x + y + 1)^5], TraditionalOrder -> True]`

Comment: How do I save it for further manipulation? `TraditionalForm` does not help in that case.

Comment: @Boogeyman you have to make a choice between "looks pretty" and "usable in further operations"; can't have both.

Comment: It is magic! Very awesome!

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

You can use a temporary dummy variable to result in the traditional ordering of multinomials.

```
tradPoly[expr_, 
  vars_] := (expr /. Thread[vars -> temp*vars] // TraditionalForm) /. temp -> 1

tradPoly[expr = (x + y + 1)^5 // Expand, {x, y}]
```

[image]

Since the wrapper is not included in the definition of `expr`, the wrapper does not affect subsequent use of `expr`

```
expr // Simplify

(* (1 + x + y)^5 *)
```

Comment: That should be `vars` not `var`, right?

Comment: @ChipHurst Thanks. Corrected typo.