# How can I sort the polynomial by the degree of $x$

Tags: polynomials, sorting

```
f1 = a x^2 + b x + c + x^3
```

> (*
>           a x^2+b x+c+x^3
>      *)

```
f1 /. x -> (x - a/3) // Expand
```

> (*
>          (2 a^3)/27-(a^2 x)/3-(a b)/3+b x+c+x^3
>      *)

I've tried this:

```
f1 /. x -> (x - a/3) // Expand // Collect[#, x] &
```

> (*
>          (2 a^3)/27+x (b-a^2/3)-(a b)/3+c+x^3
>      *)

```
f1 /. x -> (x - a/3) // Expand // Collect[#, x] & // PolynomialForm
```

> (*
>          (2 a^3)/27-(b a)/3+x^3+c+(b-a^2/3) x
>      *)

Comment: You can extract the coefficients of $x$ as a list using `f1 /. x -> (x - a/3) // CoefficientList[#, x] &`.

Answer (score 8):

Try this formatting

```
OrderedForm[x_] := HoldForm[+##] & @@ (x^#1[[1]] #2 & @@@ CoefficientRules[#, x]) &;

f1 /. x -> (x - a/3) // OrderedForm[x]
```

> ```
> x^3+(-(a^2/3)+b) x+((2 a^3)/27-(a b)/3+c)
> ```

See also my answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/33133/4678).

Answer (score 3):

The OP almost had it with attempting to use `PolynomialForm[]`. All that was missing is the use of an appropriate setting:

```
PolynomialForm[a x^2 + b x + c + x^3 /. x -> (x - a/3), 
               TraditionalOrder -> True]
   (x - a/3)^3 + a (x - a/3)^2 + b (x - a/3) + c
```

As is usual with `*Form[]` functions, this is only suitable for display/pretty printing.