# Why doesn't defined MakeBoxes display what is constructed in RHS?

Tags: function-construction, output-formatting, boxes, traditional-form

Inspired by the @ybeltukov 's answer to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37339/how-can-i-sort-the-polynomial-by-the-degree-of-x?rq=1) question, if I have the following polynomial

```
poly = a^2 + (a^2 + b^2 - c^2)*x + b^2*x^2;
var = x;
```

this generates boxes out of a polynomial to be displayed in canonical order:

```
MakeBoxes[+##] & @@ (var^#1[[1]] #2 & @@@ CoefficientRules[poly, var])
% // DisplayForm // TraditionalForm
```

> $b^2 x^2 + (a^2 +b^2 -c^2)x + a^2$

But if I use the same construction to define `MakeBoxes` for my function `mypoly` in `TraditionalForm`

```
MakeBoxes[mypoly[poly_, var_], TraditionalForm] := 
  MakeBoxes[+##] & @@ (var^#1[[1]] #2 & @@@ CoefficientRules[poly, var])
```

Then asking it to display in `TraditionalForm`

```
mypoly[a^2 + x^2 b^2 + x (a^2 + b^2 - c^2), x] // TraditionalForm
```

does not yield the correct order:

> $x(a^2 +b^2 -c^2) + a^2 +b^2 x^2$

Why? and what can I do to get the right order?

Comment: not really an answer, but if you put an `HoldForm` around the `+##` in MakeBoxes it works: `MakeBoxes[mypoly[poly_, var_], TraditionalForm] := 
  MakeBoxes[HoldForm[+##]] & @@ (var^#1[[1]] #2 & @@@ CoefficientRules[poly, var])`

Comment: @gIS but it *is* an answer.  I'll try it out as soon as I get my hands on Mathematica.

Comment: well, I mean, it solves the problem but as the question was about *why* this happens, I'm not really able to answer that! Clearly something about the order things are evaluated but I was not able to pinpoint it exactly. Something interesting is that adding that `HoldForm` changes the output only in that it wraps the resulting expression into a `TagBox`, which again I'm not really sure what it does (the docs say that `TagBox` somehow helps "guiding the interpretation of the boxes")

Comment: I had no idea you could do `+##`, nice trick.

Comment: @masterxilo Thanks, but it's actually from ybeltukov's answer in the link given at top.

Comment: @masterxilo You may be interested in [(1021)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1021/121), [(31789)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31789/121), [(31797)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31797/121), [(71348)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/71348/121)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interesting question.  Building on comments by [glS](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/27539/gls) It appears that `HoldForm` is treated specially by (conversion to) [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm.html), whereas a normal hold attribute does not prevent reordering.  This is not exactly surprising considering that formatting rules do not directly respect hold attributes. (See [Returning an unevaluated expression with values substituted in](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7880/returning-an-unevaluated-expression-with-values-substituted-in/7882#7882).)

Here is a concise example:

```
{HoldForm[b + a^2], Defer[b + a^2], HoldComplete[b + a^2]} // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Note that neither `Defer` nor `HoldComplete` prevent this reordering.  So while `MakeBoxes` has `HoldAllComplete` this is insufficient to preserve order.

Further, Box form is itself vulnerable to reordering by TraditionalForm:

```
MakeBoxes[b + a^2]
% // TraditionalForm // DisplayForm
```

> ```
> RowBox[{"b", "+", SuperscriptBox["a", "2"]}]
>
> a^2 + b
> ```

Note that the [`RowBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RowBox.html) is in the correct order but the second line *still* alters its order.

One finds that `HoldForm` becomes a `TagBox` upon box conversion.  Interestingly it seems that an arbitrary `TagBox` also prevents this reordering:

```
TagBox[RowBox[{"b", "+", SuperscriptBox["a", "2"]}], foo] // 
  TraditionalForm // DisplayForm
```

> ```
> b + a^2
> ```

```
MakeBoxes[Annotation[b + a^2]]
% // TraditionalForm // DisplayForm
```

> ```
> TagBox[RowBox[{b, +, SuperscriptBox[a, 2]}], #1 &]
>
> b + a^2
> ```

In any case it seems that including `HoldForm` is the simplest solution.  Here is an alternative formulation using `Collect` for your consideration:

```
MakeBoxes[mypoly[poly_, var_], TraditionalForm] := 
  ToBoxes @ Collect[poly, var, # &, HoldForm[+##] ~Reverse~ {2} &]
```