# How can I change the way Mathematica orders exponents?

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, output

How can I change the ascending order that Mathematica has of ordering the exponents, to a descending one.

For example, get

```
In [1]: = s ^ 2 + s + 2
Out [1] = s ^ 2 + s + 2
```

and not the traditional

```
In [1]: = s ^ 2 + s + 2
Out [1] = 2 + s + s ^ 2
```

Comment: `s^2 + s + 2 // TraditionalForm`?  See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/33130/why-does-mathematica-order-polynomial-forms-in-reverse-from-traditional-order -- See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9570/how-do-i-reassign-canonical-ordering-of-symbols

Comment: Yes but always, without having to add the // TraditionalForm

Comment: `Plus` is `Orderless`, so the ordering is canonical. You'll have to do something special, if not `TraditionalForm` then something else...

Comment: One can use e.g. `PolynomialForm[s^2 + s + 2, TraditionalOrder -> True]`, see e.g. [How to keep Collect result in order?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15744/how-to-keep-collect-result-in-order/15745#15745)

Comment: Are you just concerned about output formatting? If so, you could modify `$Post`, which is a user-definable function applied to every output expression.

Comment: @thorimur, yeah thats what I want, thxs