# How to simplify a polynomial and get the results in the order that I want?

Tags: output-formatting, polynomials, order

How to simplify a polynomial in a order that I want?

Assume that I have a polynomial here, for example, $a^3 b^4 c^2$, the order of symbels is the dictionary order, $a>b>c$. But what if I want in a order $b>a>c$?

This is convenient for Abelian algebra, but inconvenient for non-Abelian algebra. Actually, I am using a *Mathematica* package about [Quantum Notation](http://homepage.cem.itesm.mx/lgomez/quantum/) by José Luis Gómez-Muñoz, and I want to reduce a series product of quantum operator to a [normal order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_order) -- creation is always after annihilation, or creation is always to the left of annihilation.

So, what should I do? Could I add a condition to `Simplify`? Or is there such a function in the package that I use?

Comment: I have marked this question as a duplicate because as I read it I believe it is.  Please review that question and its answers.  If they do not solve your problem please edit your question to explain how what you need is different and I shall reopen it.

Comment: Related: [(6358)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6358/121),
[(15744)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15744/121),
[(20714)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20714/121),
[(30216)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30216/121)