# Rounding only coefficients

Tags: output-formatting, polynomials

does Mathematica have built in functionality to round the coefficients of a polynomial to a certain accuracy. Say, we do

```
Print[0.2134320980x^2+0.0023432x]
```

Can we wrap a function around the expression in the print so that the output is

> ```
> 0.213x^2+0.002x
> ```

I tried `NumberForm` but this rounds messes with the exponent. Thank you!

Comment: If exponents are integers then you can use quick approach: `0.2134320980 x^2 + 0.0023432 x /. r_Real :> Round[r, .001]`

Comment: works pretty well. can it be also done that it adds zeros if the original number was too short?

Comment: @kuba - yours answer would also round the exponents, which works in this case, but not for multi-digit exponents. The question was: "Round only coefficients".

Comment: @ kuba - OK, I have to improve my reading, sorry for that :)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are asking about polynomials only (where exponents are integers from definition) with real coefficients:

```
expr = 0.2134320980 x^2 + 0.0023432 x + .2 x^3;
(HoldForm[#] &@expr) /. c_Real :> NumberForm[c, {∞, 3}]
```

> ```
> 0.002 x + 0.213 x^2 + 0.200 x^3
> ```

You may use one of the methods introduced here: [20714](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20714/5478) to preserve traditional order:

```
f = HoldForm[+##] & @@ MonomialList@# &;
f[expr] /. c_Real :> NumberForm[c, {∞, 3}]
```

> ```
> 0.200 x^3 + 0.213 x^2 + 0.002 x
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = 0.2134320980 x^2 + 0.0023432 x;

a /. Times[b_, c_] :> Times[Round[b, 0.0001], c]
```

> 0.0023 x + 0.2134 x^2