# How to convert the following list into a LaTeX table?

Tags: list-manipulation, latex

How to convert the output of the following code

```
In[43]:= Func[x_]:=Select[Range[x],Total[IntegerDigits[#]^3]==#&];
Func[1000]
```

which is

> Out[44]= {1,153,370,371,407}

to the following form

[image]

such that I can copy it and paste to my LaTeX document without significant hassle.

### Edit

I want the output of Mathematica to be consumable for LaTeX engine.

```
1^3 & 1\\
1^3+5^3+3^3 & 153\\
3^3+7^3+0^3 & 370\\
3^3+7^3+1^3 & 371\\
4^3+0^3+7^3 & 407\\
```

Comment: Do you want to generate the first column or are you after the $LaTeX$ export part?

Comment: @YvesKlett: The table contents must be generated by Mathematica so I can just copy and paste.

Comment: You are aware of `TeXForm`? E.g. `Grid[{{a, b, c}, {x, y^2, z^3}}, Frame -> All] // TeXForm` ...

Comment: @YvesKlett: Please show me how can you decompose each element of the list into the sum of cubes and make sure it is not evaluated.

Comment: Please add that info to your question to help understand it better.

Comment: You could wait if other and better answers come in (I hope so!) and accept after a few days. Questions with accepted answers tend to attract fewer new answers...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Modding the `plus` part from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14094/131), this could be a (somewhat awkward because you get more `array` than you asked for) start:

```
Func[x_] := Select[Range[x], Total[IntegerDigits[#]^3] == # &];
nums = Func[1000];

plus[args__] := Grid[{Riffle[{args}, "+"]}]

g = Grid[{plus @@ (IntegerDigits[#] /. x_Integer :> HoldForm[x^3]) & /@
      nums, nums} // Transpose]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
TeXForm[g]
```

returns unnecessarily complicated output, which compiles just fine (and looks indeed much better than standard frontend output).

[image]

As for further styling, this is perhaps better done in your document - unless you have to do that many times over, in which case you could roll your own `MyOwnTeXForm`.

Side note: If everything else fails, you can install the Computer Modern fonts and use them with `Style` to do all the formatting in the frontend - and then export an image (not pretty, but it works).

Comment: Strange thing that `Row[{args}, "+"]` produces errors during converting to TeX. Moreover, `Dividers` result in not good TeX output. But your code is ok and adding dividers in TeX is not a big deal I suppose.

Comment: @Kuba yes, that was the reason to switch over to Grid.